# Firefox extension question

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to make a Firefox extension so everytime you access a certains website you also see a box with an information, either integrated in the website or not. For example everytime you access google homepage you get a box with some information independent to the searches you make.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Any other question?

Comment: is it possible the information to look like it was part of that website? and do I need any sort of permission from the website owner in that case?

Comment: Well, if you add elements to the site, the defined styles will also apply to them. If you need the permission: That might depend on what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of approaches you could take.

You can avoid the complexity of doing an extension if you simply write a [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) script. There are a ton of example scripts at [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/) that you should be able to search for ways to approach your particular project.

If you want to distribute it as an extension, I'd suggest using the [Addon SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/). It makes it really easy to develop and package an extension, and provides a framework called [page-mods](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) to modify pages.